# Central limit theorem replacing radical n with n

Tags: probability, central-limit-theorem, asymptotics

Does $n(y_n-\mu) \overset{\mathbb d}{\to} \mathcal N(0,\sigma^2/ n^2),$ remembering that $n^{1/2}(y_n-\mu) \overset{\mathbb d}{\to} \mathcal N(0,\sigma^2)?$

Comment: Welcome to Cross Validated! What would it mean to converge to a moving target?

Comment: What is the meaning of the $\sigma^2$ that appears in one limit but not in the other?

Comment: I’m sorry.I made a mistake .

Comment: Possibly you meant to write $$n(y_n-\mu) \overset{\mathbb d}{\to} \mathcal N(0,n\sigma^2)$$

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are 3 issues

#### 1) notation $\overset{\mathbb P}{\to}$ versus $\overset{\mathbb d}{\to}$

<sup>This you have already edited/corrected in your question.</sup>

The notation $\overset{\mathbb P}{\to}$ means convergence in probability.

With the central limit theorem we use, the notation $\overset{\mathbb d}{\to}$, which means convergence in distribution.

#### 2) The variance $n\sigma^2$ versus $\sigma^2/n^2$

Possibly you meant to write $$n(y_n-\mu) \overset{\mathbb d}{\to} \mathcal N(0,n\sigma^2)$$

Instead of

$$n(y_n-\mu) \overset{\mathbb d}{\to} \mathcal N(0,\sigma^2/n^2)$$

The asymptotic behaviour of the variance is $$\text{Var}\left( n(y_n-\mu)\right) \sim n \sigma^2$$

#### 3) Convergence versus asymptotic equivalence

Convergence relates to a limit, like the distribution function approaching some other function.

$X_n \overset{\mathbb P}{\to} \mathcal f(x) $

means that for all values of $x$ we have the limiting behaviour:

$$\forall x: \left\{ \lim_{n \to \infty} P(X_n<x) = f(x) \right\}$$

Or in your example

$$\forall y: \left\{\lim_{n \to \infty} P\left(\frac{Y_n-\mu}{\sigma n ^{1/2}} \leq y \right) = \Phi(y) \right\}$$

A limit/convergence, using the notation $\to$, has always a fixed constant value or function on the right side. When the right side is changing, then we speak about asymptotic behaviour. This is denoted with a tilde, $\sim$, see for instance the Wikipedia article about this topic [definition of asymptotic equility relationship](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Asymptotic_analysis#Definition) (not to be confused with the [tilde notation in statistics](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/531826)).

It wouldn't be bad to have the right side change as well (although you would need find a different, less confusing, notation for it) and we could say that it means:

$$\tag{1}\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{P\left(Y_n \leq y \right)}{\Phi\left( \frac{y-\mu}{n^{1/2}\sigma} \right)}= 1 $$

But this is a different statement than

$$\tag{2} \lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{P\left(\frac{Y_n-\mu}{\sigma n ^{1/2}} \leq y \right)}{ \Phi(y)} = 1$$

You may have that equation 1 does not hold for every value of $y$ while equation 2 does hold for every value of $y$.

Example:

In the image below you see the distribution of the mean of 100 Bernoulli distributed variables. It does *not* approach a normal distribution in the sense that the limit of the ratio goes to 1. Close to zero this ratio remains zero (and this doesn't get better when we increase $n$).

[image: counter example]

#### In your case,

If

- you would define the equivalence relationship

  $$f_n(x) \approx g_n(x)$$

  as denoting asymptotic equivalence for the two distribution functions and more specifically as

  $$\forall x: \left\{\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{F_n(x)}{G_n(x)}  = 1 \right\}$$

  where $F$ and $G$ relate to the cumulative distribution functions generated by the probability density functions $f$ and $g$.

Then

- You can state that $$n(y_n-\mu) = \sum_{i=1}^n (y_i-\mu) \approx \mathcal N(0,n\sigma^2)$$

It is not common, but this expression for asymptotic normality is not entirely absent. For example in Barndorff-Nielsen, Ole E., and David Roxbee Cox. [Asymptotic techniques for use in statistics](https://books.google.nl/books?&id=UQ9yIrZpMToC&dq=barndorff+asymptotic&focus=searchwithinvolume&q=%22we+sometimes+write%22).

> The sequence $\lbrace V_n \rbrace$ is asymptotically normal if there exist sequences of constants $\lbrace a_n \rbrace, \lbrace b_n\rbrace$ such that $(V_n - a_n)/b_n $ converges in distribution to the standard normal distribution. The constants $a_n, b_n$ are called
> respectively the asymptotic mean and standard deviation of $V_n$.
>
> We sometimes write $V_n \sim aN(a_n, b_n^2)$. Asymptotic normality is
> concerned with...

Although this does not define $\sim$ very clearly and may be more like an abuse of notation and $V_n \sim aN(a_n, b_n^2)$ means $(V_n-a_n)/b_n \sim N(0, 1)$ and not the asymptotic equivalence relationship that I described before.

Answer (score 8):

Notice a few things.

1. If we compute the variance of the LHS, $\text{Var}(n(y_n-y)) = n^2\text{Var}(y_n)$. However, $y_n = \frac{1}{n}(x_1+...+x_n)$ where the $(x_i)_{1\leq i\leq n}$ are i.i.d. (I am assuming based on your notation). Therefore, $\text{Var}(y_n) = \tfrac{1}{n^2}(n\cdot \sigma^2) = \tfrac{\sigma^2}{n}$. We conclude from here that the variance of the LHS is equal to $n\cdot \sigma^2$. As $n\to \infty$ this quantity blows up to infinity and there is no limit.
2. As $n\to \infty$ the quantity $\frac{\sigma^2}{n^2}\to 0$, therefore you are suggesting that the distribution of $n(y_n-y)$ converges in distribution to $N(0,0)$ which looks very suspicious.

Answer (score 2):

No, write
$$n(y_n-\mu)=n^{1/2}n^{1/2}(y_n-\mu)$$
From $n^{1/2}(y_n-\mu) \overset{\mathbb d}{\to} \mathcal N(0,\sigma^2)=O_p(1)$ (cf. e.g. [root-n consistent estimator, but root-n doesn't converge?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/207264/root-n-consistent-estimator-but-root-n-doesnt-converge/207281#207281)) we find $$n(y_n-\mu)=O_p(n^{1/2})$$ we obtain something which diverges whereas, as Nicolas has pointed out, $N(0,\sigma^2/ n^2)$ tends to a degenerate r.v. at zero, so basically the constant zero.